# Setting up artifactory on Ubuntu: ERROR: cannot find a JRE or JDK

Tags: ubuntu, artifactory, java-home

When attempting to install artifactory, I run the following command:

```
 sudo service artifactory check
```

I get the following output:

```
Created output file /root/artifactory-2.3.2/logs/consoleout.log
Cannot find a JRE or JDK. Please set JAVA_HOME to a >=1.5 JRE
```

I used the following to get my java home:

```
# which java
/usr/bin/java
```

I have added the java home to the etc/artifactory/default as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
```

My /etc/environment looks like:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/java"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are setting up a new server, please consider using the latest Artifactory 3. The improvements list over 2.3 is too long to fit in the comment. I'll just mention it should be at least 10 times faster.

Answer (score 2):

JAVA_HOME should be set to the directory one level above the "bin" subdirectory containing the Java executable file, not the file itself.  /usr/bin/java on Ubuntu is a symlink to the actual Java installation.  Find the actual directory like this (I pasted the commands from my system):

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 2012-06-14 17:33 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java*
$ ls -l /etc/alternative/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 2012-06-14 17:33 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java*
```

So in my case JAVA_HOME should be set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle - your system may be different.

You should also add the bin subdirectory to your PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Try typing

```
java -version
```

from the command line to test out your settings.